# Download CSV URL as .csv file using Javascript (HTML content formatted as CSV)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, download

How can I download an html page where my content is already formatted as csv.

I keep finding how to export JSON to csv, or data table to csv, but nothing on how to actually download a html content formatted as csv to an actual .csv file on page load.

Thanks in advance for your help.

see my code below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/Pulling-JSON-Data.js"></script>

<script>

    $('html').append(
        "Category 1, Category 2, Category 3" +
        "<br/>"
    );

    $(dataName).each(function(index) {
            $('html').append(
                "&quot;" + this.exemple1 + "&quot;," + 
                "&quot;" + this.exemple2 + "&quot;," + 
                "&quot;" + this.exemple3 + "&quot;," +          
                "<br />"
            );
        });


    var CSVdata = document.createElement('a');
    CSVdata.href = "data:application/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(dataName);
    CSVdata.target = '_blank';
    CSVdata.download = 'file.csv';
    CSVdata.click();

</script>
```

Comment: You can make an AJAX call directly to the .csv file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: This seems to be exporting my html instead of what I have in the front-end which is what I need to download.